# How can I set my Kindle Paperwhite to ignore font color settings?

Tags: kindle, mobi, fonts, kindle-paperwhite, color

I bought an e-book from a 3rd party bookstore which looks really bad on my Kindle Paperwhite. I've investigated the book and it seems to me that the basic font color is defined to be grey instead of black.

```
p { ....; color: #231f20 }
```

Is there a way to set my Kindle just to ignore the built-in style sheet and use the default black as a font color?

*I've fixed the book using Calibre by manually changing #231f20 to #000000 but I still looking for a more universal solution.*

Comment: Does converting the .mobi to .azw3 in Calibre change the color to pure black? I bet there are containers that don't support alternative colors, and conversion would revert the color.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you have bought pure ePub and later converted it to Mobi, you could delete the color attribute at all (Kindle will treat this with it’s built in color spec.). This needs unpacking of ePub, deleting the css part you have mentioned and proper packing into ePub again.